# Http requests in Android: Good use of Singleton or static class?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, singleton

I generally dislike the usage of singletons or static class, since I can refactor them to something different most of the time.

However, I am currently designing my access point to a HTTP API on an Android app, and I was thinking that I have the following environment:

- I need to send HTTP requests in the majority of my code modules (Activities).
- The code for sending a request does not depend on the request being sent
- There will always only be one specific user on the app per session (unlike the server-side that has to handle different users etc)

Therefore, I was thinking that this could be a situation where it is justifiable to use a Singleton, or even a static class, to place HTTP requests - In the rest of my code, I would then simply have to use something like:

```
MyHttpAccess.attemptLogin(name, pass, callback)
```

in order to complete the request. I'm even leaning towards using a static class, as I do not have any variable data that I can think of needing to store.

Does this seem like good or bad design, and what should I potentially change?

Comment: It's ok to have a singleton and if you are not passing any strong reference such as context, views etc. you can also use static. I would use a singleton with dependency injection. If the project is simple and using Kotlin then an `object LoginUtil { fun attemptLogin() {} }` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Http Request in kotlin using single class

https://medium.com/@umesh8346/android-kotlin-api-integration-different-method-b5b84eb4f386